# change surrounding tags for a given text by RegExp

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create function that find text in my htmlString (it minify) and then change the tag that wrap the text to h2

```
 var htmlString = `
<h1>title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><p>hi</p><p>hi 123</p><div>hi</div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit.</span>
`
const changeTagByText = (html) => {
let text = "hi"

// replace the tags

return html
}

console.log(changeTagByText(html))
```

output excepted:

```
<h1>title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><h2>hi</h2><p>hi 123</p><h2>hi</h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit.</span>
```

Comment: I really hope with changes in title it will get more attention(but you can revert it back, if you want to)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

```js
var htmlString = `<h1>title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><p>hi</p><p>hi 123</p><div>hi</div><span>hi</span><span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit.</span>
`
const changeTagByText = (html, word) => {
  var re = new RegExp('(<[a-zA-Z]+>)'+ word +'(</[a-zA-Z]+>)', 'g')
  return html.replace(re, '<h1>'+ word +'</h1>');
}
console.log(changeTagByText(htmlString, 'hi'))
```

You can do it more dynamically by expand `changeTagByText` to take two params one for the html and the other one for the text you want to replace.

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) help to create dynamic regex pattern.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work with minify string.


var htmlString = `
<h1>title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><p>hi</p><p>hi 123</p><div>hi</div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit.</span>
`

Comment: Can you check mu last update